# why i need clear stringstream before reuse?

Tags: c++, stringstream

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 10;
    string str;
    stringstream toString;
    toString << num;
    toString >> str;
    cout << str << "\n"; //10

    int num2 = 20;
    string str2;
    toString << num2;
    toString >> str2;
    cout << str2 << "\n"; //str2 is empty
    return 0;
}
```

I know that I must clear this like:

```
toString.str("");
toString.clear();
```

But why doesn't it clear automatically after using operator `>>`?

Comment: Why would it? What if there's more stuff in the stream that you want to get later?

Comment: You may wish to use a series of >> operators before checking the flags.

Comment: Similar reason to why `cout` doesn't automatically print a new line after every `<<`

Comment: Don't name a stream object `toString`.

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦, and what is a proper name?

Comment: [Don't use `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `toString` already has a specific meaning to other programmers.  Almost any other name would be preferable; even `myStream` or simply `s` would suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I do `toString >> a >> b >> c` and the first one fails, I don't want the flag to be cleared so that the final state appears to have succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

After the first read `toString >> str;`. then the `rdstate()` of `toString` is `std::ios_base::eofbit`, because during the reading of `str` the end of the string has been reached.

Then the line `toString << num2;` does not modify the string stored in `toString` but sets the `failbit` of `toString`. That is the standard behavior of all [formatted output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedOutputFunction).

The line `toString >> str2;` does nothing: the `failbit` is already set, and no reading is performed: `str2` stays empty.

The [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function resets the `rdstate()` of `toString` to `std::ios_base::goodbit`.

The reasons why the `>>` must *not* call `clear()` are:

1. in case there is an error, then one must be able to test it using the functions `bad()`, `fail()`, `eof()` (or `rdstate()` directly),
2. and one can use the operator `>>` several times:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstream>

   int main() {
     std::stringstream sstr("10 20");
     int i, j;
     sstr >> i >> j;
     if(!sstr.fail()) {
       std::cout << i << " " << j << "\n";
       return 0;
     }
     return 1;
   }
   ```